# how can I check when the last list item has been deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have 10 tweets inside a  with an id #comments each list item has a class (.comment) you can delete each comment, what I'm trying to do is that when you delete the last

then I'll make an ajax call to bring more comments. Any ideas on how to approach this?

this is what I've been trying to do without any luck

```
if $('#comments li').length <= 3
    $.ajax
      url: "#{url}?last_id=#{last_id}&ml_category=#{ml_category}"
      type: "GET"
      beforeSend: ->
        btn.text translations['loading_comments_text']
      success: (data) ->
        position = last_comment.offset().top + last_comment.height()
        btn.remove()
        $('#comments').append data
        $('html,body').animate
          scrollTop: 0
          , 1000
        $('.relatable_campaign').tooltip()
        btn.attr 'data-id', $('.comment:last').data('id')
        btn.attr 'data-ml-category', $('.comment:last').data('ml-category')
        $('select').select2()
        checkTotalComments()

      error: (xhr, settings, thrownError) ->
        btn.text translations['loading_comments_error_text']
```

The ajax call works fine when I used to have a load more comments, but since we don;t want that button anymore now we want to listen for when there are no more comments and then append new one.

Comment: why dont you try in your delete comment function if($('.comment').length==0){loadMoreComments();} ?

Comment: yes that was one approach the thing is what if they don't delete the comment what if the choose to reply instead, so if it is the last comment and they reply instead of deleting it then the delete comment function won't take effect. I was thinking about listening for the whole container #comments and whenever there are not more <li> then call the ajax event.

Comment: Well, you could add same check to your reply function or listen for domTreeModified on your #comments

Comment: yeah, the thing is I can't add the function to the delete comment function, so what I was asked to do is to check when there are no more comments and then make the ajax call to get more comments. I tried several ways to listen for when the last li.comment is gone from the page which would mean the <ul> with the id='#comments' is empty and then I could make another ajax request. I've tried several ways to listen for that event without any luck. I've listen for when the comments li length is equals to 0 $('#comments li.comment').length === 0 but didn't work

Comment: I've also tried with an ajaxComplete function and listen for the length on the last comment, and that responds everytime delete one comment instead of working on the last comment $(document).ajaxComplete(event, request, settings) ->
  $('#comments .comment:last').length is 0

Comment: Have you tried using $('#comments').on('change', function(){}) ?